# Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried so many times changing the variable name even copied from original source code but still, I don't understand why error property shows you declared the error property but never used but in the video where I've learned its working just fine. I can't even access my data which is in the database [For checking purpose I used `console.log` statement but still, I didn't get my data ]. Anybody, please help me why I have this problem.

Here is the image of error I'm getting [image]

### CODE

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Base from '../core/Base';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getCategories } from './helper/adminapicall';
import { isAuthenticated } from '../auth/helper/index';

const AddProduct = () => {
  const { user, token } = isAuthenticated();

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    description: '',
    price: '',
    stock: '',
    photo: '',
    categories: [],
    category: '',
    loading: false,
    error: '',
    createdProduct: '',
    getaRedirect: false,
    formData: '',
  });

  const {
    name,
    description,
    price,
    stock,
    categories,
    category,
    loading,
    error,
    createdProduct,
    getaRedirect,
    formData,
  } = values;

  const preload = () => {
    getCategories().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
      } else {
        setValues({ ...values, categories: data, formData: new FormData() });
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    preload();
  }, []);

const createProductForm = () => (
    <form>
      <span>Post photo</span>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <label className='btn btn-block btn-success'>
          <input
            onChange={handleChange('photo')}
            type='file'
            name='photo'
            accept='image'
            placeholder='choose a file'
          />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange('name')}
          name='photo'
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='Name'
          value={name}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <textarea
          onChange={handleChange('description')}
          name='photo'
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='Description'
          value={description}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange('price')}
          type='number'
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='Price'
          value={price}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <select
          onChange={handleChange('category')}
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='Category'>
          <option>Select</option>
          {categories &&
            categories.map((cate, index) => (
              <option key={index} value={cate._id}>
                {cate.name}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange('quantity')}
          type='number'
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='Stock'
          value={stock}
        />
      </div>

      <button
        type='submit'
        onClick={onSubmit}
        className='btn btn-outline-success mb-3'>
        Create Product
      </button>
    </form>
  );

  return (
    <Base
      title='Add a product here!'
      description='Welcome to product creation section'
      className='container bg-info p-4'>
      <Link to='/admin/dashboard' className='btn btn-md btn-dark mb-3'>
        Admin Home
      </Link>
      <div className='row bg-dark text-white rounded'>
        <div className='col-md-8 offset-md-2'>{createProductForm()}</div>
      </div>
    </Base>
  );
};

export default AddProduct;
```

Comment: *"For checking purpose I used console.log statement but still, I didn't get my data"* So `data` is `undefined`? That would explain the error (which is pretty clear IMO). Not sure what you expect us to do. You are not showing us the implementation of `getCategories` so we can't really help you with getting the data correctly.

Comment: *"I don't understand why error property shows you declared the error property but never used"* That sounds more like a linter warning and might refer to the fact that you are declaring the error *variable/constant*  but you are not reading from it (at least not in the code you posted). That's not related to fetching the data though and is the lesser of the issues.

Comment: make console log for data first, make sure you have a variable called data, then see what you will get,

Comment: Are you using axios inside `getCategories()`?

Comment: @CodeBug I've to console log the data is not showing  but  in my database, there is some data I already created

Comment: "*I've to console log the data is not showing but in my database, there is some data I already created*". This means that the problem is in the `getCategories()` or in your backend implementation.

Comment: Errors are caught inside the `.catch()` method using `error.response.data`. I don't understand why you're catching errors inside `.then()`.

Comment: @narayanmaity you created data in the database but you didn't call that or used that in your code so your getting error, define variable it will work.

Comment: @CodeBug Actually this is not the full code there are another 100 lines of code which I didn't post there I actually called the categories. I've made it readable for programmers.

Comment: @jstarnate No, I'm not using Axios I'm using fetch method

Comment: @narayanmaity You should be catching errors in `.catch()`, not in `.then()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getCategories().then(data => {
  if (data && data.error) {
    setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
  } else {
    setValues({ ...values, categories: data, formData: new FormData() });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, @John V it worked the error is gone but still my categories data is not showing I'm updating the question plz check it will be really helpful